# How do you assign a certain grid area to a class and then different one to its child element?

Tags: css, css-grid

On my [website](https://www.downloads.qalamproject.org/beta.html), I want to assign the .about class grid-columns: 1/4; while for the .about h1 element, I want that to be in grid-column: 3/4 and the .about p element to be in grid-column: 1/2;

I have already tried to the needed lines to the child elements in my css file but nothing seems to change on the site when I do.

```css
css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(min-content, 30vh) minmax(min-content, 20vh) 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background: gray;
  /* grid-gap: 10px; */
}

  /* about */
  .about {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    padding: 3rem 1rem 1.25rem;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
    .about h1 {
      grid-column: 3/4;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 100;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      color: #1a202c;
    }

    .about p {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: #4a5568;
    }

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #38b2ac;
  transition: 0.35s;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0.25rem 1rem 0.75rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="hero">
    <h1>Lorem text</h1>
    <button class="btn">learn now</button>
    <button class="rev btn">about us</button>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <h1>Who we are</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas facilisis lacus vitae ipsum laoreet, nec vulputate leo euismod. Aliquam id nunc ut ipsum gravida iaculis. Morbi sit amet rhoncus justo. Quisque maximus eros eget feugiat blandit. Proin pharetra purus in urna ornare imperdiet. Donec convallis tortor nec aliquet blandit. Donec id imperdiet mi.
</p>
    <button class="btn">read more</button>
  </section>
```

Comment: ..but note that `.about` is **not** `display:grid` nor have you defined any columns for it.

Comment: added a snippet. my grid is in class .container and I want the .about class to be in 1/4 and the specific child elements in 3/4 and 1/2

Comment: Your children elements are not direct descendants of a `grid` parent.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  Ah yes! I read that too quickly.

Comment: @disinfor , I am not sure what you mean by that. I am applying the .container class then the .about class. The .container class is the one that is display:grid , and I am assigning it to all three columns by using grid-columns: 1/4; I am having issues with getting the h1 and p child elements of the .about class in the right position

Comment: You can't position elements on the grid unless **their parent** is `display:grid` and CSS-Grid is not inherited.

Comment: @pandaman82 here's a hint: your `.about` class needs to have `display: grid`

Answer (score 0):

With css grid, only direct children of the parent element can be arranged. Since `div.container` has `display: grid`, only `section.hero` and `section.about` can be placed in grid areas.

You can use `display: contents` to "flatten" the tree., making the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements accessible to your grid layout.

```
.about {
  display: contents;
}
```

Now, on the css level, you have four children of `div.container`: `div.hero` and all three children of `div.about` (`<h1>`,`<p>`, and `<button>`). That means you'll have to place the `<button>` element, which you haven't done in your code.

Otherwise, you'll need to rethink your markup/layout.

I recommend reading `[CSS Tricks' A Complete Guide to Grid][1]`.